# Box topology definition

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, product-space

Munkres defines the box topology as shown below. I am trying to understand how come an element of basis as defined is even subset of $\prod_{\alpha \in J}X_{\alpha}$. If we get an element of the basis, then it is $\prod_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha}$, where $U_{\alpha}$ is open in $X_{\alpha}$. $\prod_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha} = \{ f : J \rightarrow \bigcup_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha} : f(\alpha) \in U_{\alpha} \}$, which isn't subset of $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$ as $\bigcup_{\alpha \in J}U_{\alpha}$ isn't equal to $\bigcup_{\alpha \in J}X_{\alpha}$ in general right ? So, how come it is a subset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $A_\alpha\subseteq B_\alpha$, then $\bigcup A_\alpha\subseteq\bigcup B_\alpha$. This is an easy exercise, which I am leaving to you.

And if $f\colon X\to Y$, and $Y\subseteq W$, then $f$ is also a function from $X$ into $W$. Because functions in this context are sets of ordered pairs, not triplets of domain, codomain and "rule". And even if they are, we can replace $\subseteq$ by some relevant notion to match this definition.

Therefore every function in $\prod U_\alpha$ is in particular a function in $\prod X_\alpha$. So it is indeed a subset of the product.

Comment: I am little bit confused. Munkres mentioned that $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is different than $f` : X \rightarrow B \subset Y$ as sets, which I didn't understand fully. Could you maybe shed some light on this issue for me ?

Comment: In this case you can consider $f\colon J\to\bigcup U_\alpha$ as a function from $J$ into $\bigcup X_\alpha$ which "just happens to only hit inside $U_\alpha$". Namely, compose this with the natural inclusion morphism.

Comment: I guess we can always change the range appropriately, but wouldn't we then require a separate definition for product of subsets of a set?

Comment: I see that is what I thought I wanted to have a assurance that is correct. Thank you!

Comment: Meh, that's just another "win" for the notion of functions as sets of ordered pairs, rather than a bunch of triplets. The point is that mathematicians are often lazy and abuse notation and context in hope that the reader understands the implicit changes necessary to be formally correct. Often it's easy to infer what's the general idea missing, but sometimes it can be confusing (and sometimes outright mistaken!).

Comment: Yeah I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f\in\prod_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha$; then $f(\alpha)\in U_\alpha$ for each $\alpha\in J$. And for each $\alpha\in J$ we have $U_\alpha\subseteq X_\alpha$, so $f(\alpha)\in X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha\in J$, which by definition means that $f\in\prod_{\alpha\in J}X_\alpha$.

Comment: isn't the range different though, so why $f \in \prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$.

Comment: @TheKEMO: See my answer.

Comment: @TheKEMO: The range is completely irrelevant; all that matters is whether or not $f(\alpha)$ is an element of $X_\alpha$, and if it’s an element of $U_\alpha$, then it’s certainly an element of $X_\alpha$. If Munkres says that $f:X\to Y$ and $f:X\to B$, where $f[X]\subseteq B\subsetneqq Y$, are different **as sets**, he’s simply wrong.

Comment: Why is that true can you please explain ?

Comment: @TheKEMO: A function $f:X\to Y$ is simply a subset of $X\times Y$ such that $(1)$ if $\langle x,y_0\rangle\in f$ and $\langle x,y_1\rangle\in f$, then $y_0=y_1$, and $(2)$ for each $x\in X$ there is a $y\in Y$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in f$; $(1)$ and $(2)$ together are equivalent to saying that for each $x\in X$ there is a unique $y\in Y$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in f$, and we denote this $y$ by $f(x)$. If the set $B$ contains all of these elements $f(x)$, then $f\subseteq X\times B$, $(1)$ is still true, and so is $(2')$: for each $x\in X$ there is a $y\in B$ such that ...

Comment: ... $\langle x,y\rangle\in f$. By definition, then, $f$ is a function from $X$ to $B$, so we can write $f:X\to B$, and **it’s the same set of ordered pairs**.

Comment: I see I understand thank you so much as well !

Comment: @TheKEMO: You’re welcome!